# Spark consumes more heap memory. is it true?

Tags: apache-spark

With respect to heap memory.

Spark consumes more heap memory comparative Hadoop.

Please advice me.

Comment: What is your question, you need to ask specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Starting Apache Spark version 1.6.0, memory management model has changed. The old memory management model is implemented by StaticMemoryManager class, and now it is called “legacy”. “Legacy” mode is disabled by default, which means that running the same code on Spark 1.5.x and 1.6.0 would result in different behavior, be careful with that. For compatibility, you can enable the “legacy” model with spark.memory.useLegacyMode parameter, which is turned off by default.

It's also based on your heap configuration.